# CI Router no result 404 error

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, routes

I'm working on a project to get a vanity_url to resolve a record from the database.

e.g. abc.com/ThisRecord -> shows the record from database where vanity_url=ThisRecord

In the route file I have used this:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'listing_controller/list_page/$1'; // Resolved the Vanity_URL Query
```

How would I get an error 404 if no such record exists?

Answer (score 2):

CodeIgniter has a `show_404()` function which will send an HTTP 404 header and return the template found in: `application/errors/error_404.php`. See the [user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html) for more information.

When calling the `list_page()` function, you just need to check if the record exists. If the record does exist, load the relevant view, otherwise, call the `show_404()` function.

```php
function list_page($id)
{
    if (/* the record exists */)
    {
        // The record does exist - do what you want, load a view etc.
        $this->load->view('your_view');
    }
    else
    {
        // The record doesn't exist, show the 404 page
        show_404();
    }
}
```